# Show that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\sin(nx) \,dx = 0$ for a continuous $f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

Prove that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\sin(nx) \,dx = 0$

Seems like I can say that f has its maximum and minimum (Let's call them $m_1$ and $m_2$) and than say that:

$m_1\int_{0}^{1} \sin(nx) \,dx  \leq \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\sin(nx) \,dx \leq m_2\int_{0}^{1} \sin(nx) \,dx $

And the question is about to prove that $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(nx) \,dx$ tends to 0 for big $n's$. But how can I prove it?

Comment: I fixed my question and added some additional context. Thank you for pointing out my mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

- Prove the result for a constant map.
- Then for a step function.
- Conclude by approximating $f$ with step functions. *Any continuous map is the uniform limit of step functions.*

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider the value of $\int_{\epsilon_0}^{\epsilon_1} f(x)\sin(nx)dx$ for $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$ so close to each other that $f(x)$ is approximately constant on $[\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1]$ and $n$ so large that $\sin(nx)$ makes at least one full cycle over the interval.